# Oracle SQL Server connect button is unvisible

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i was click new connecttion button this screen is open but connect button is unvisible. I think there is no problem jdk path or about jdk version so i checked it.
Additionaly i use macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and jdk 1.8.0_121.

I tried to test connection and it gave this error "**the network adapter could not establish the connection"**

Do you have any idea about this issue?

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baO3S.png)

Comment: Did you try `Test` button?

Comment: yes i did it. But still it gives an error like questions in specified bold character.

Comment: If the test fails, connect would fail too; perhaps the version of SQL Developer you're using is trying to disable the connect button when it knows there's a problem, though I don't recall seeing that happen. Anyway, make sure you can ping the host name you've specified, and then see if you can telnet to port 1523, all from the same Mac. Ae you sure the port is supposed to be 1523, not 1521? Once the test works, then see if the connect button is shown/working.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Actually i think there is a two different problem. First one is test connection is not success and the other one is unvisible connect button. I going to try to download again.
I am sure port number because other teammate use this port. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
I created new oracle account and downloaded Version 4.1.5.21.
Now connection button is visible. I will fix test connection error, i don't know how can make it but there is a lot of title about this topic on the internet. [button is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40TUx.png)